# How to work with user-inputted amount of variables?

Tags: python

how is it going? Basically my question is about visualizing the 3x+1 mathematical problem using python. I have written some code with witch we can create a graph with three user-inputted numbers, but I want the user to first specify the amount of numbers they are going to work with, then write all of them. Then the program would calculate their path with the rules provided, and would plot a graph with the results. However, I could not think how achieving that might be possible. Any ideas?

Here's the code I have written so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = int(input("Enter the number 1 :"))
b = int(input("Enter the number 2: "))
f = int(input("Enter the number 3: "))
c = []
a = []
d = []
while n != 1:
    while b != 1:
        while f != 1:
            if n % 2 == 0:
                n = n / 2
                print(n)
                a.append(n)
                if b % 2 == 0:
                    b = b / 2
                    print(b)
                    c.append(b)
                    if f % 2 == 0:
                        f = f / 2
                        print(f)
                        d.append(f)
            elif n % 2 != 0:
                n = n * 3 + 1
                print(n)
                a.append(n)
                if b % 2 != 0:
                    b = b * 3 + 1
                    print(b)
                    c.append(b)
                    if f % 2 != 0:
                        f = f * 3 + 1
                        print(f)
                        d.append(f)
else:
    print(n)
    print(b)
    print(f)
plt.plot(a, color='green', marker='o',mfc='pink' )
plt.plot(c, color='magenta', marker='o',mfc='blue' )
plt.plot(d, color='red', marker='o', mfc='yellow' )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

just do an array and loop

```py
variables = []
existLoop = False
print("Enter a number or enter q to continue")
while(existLoop == False):
    value = input("Enter the number {number}:".format(number=len(variables) + 1))
    if value != 'q':
       variables.append(int(value))
    else:
     existLoop = True

# now you can work with the array of numbers
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But how can I calculate the path for all the numbers at the same time? And then create plots for all of them( for the graph?) I'm sorry if these are dumb questions I'm just new to python

Comment: @SamedAlizade convert your hard code logic into a dynamic approach